# Resources to learn hard analysis

Tags: number-theory, analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for book (or any other resource) recommendations to practice "epsilonics", and technical analysis of the asymptotics of integer sequences (or real sequences), hard analytical estimates, etc.

To give an example of what I have in mind, the following is from a paper of Erdos on the number of partitions $p(n)$ of a positive integer $n$.

> Let $d=\liminf \frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}}$, $D=\limsup \frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}}$, where $c=\pi\sqrt{2/3}$. Since $p(n)$ is an increasing function of $n$ there exists a $c_2$ such that for every $m$ in the range $n \le m \le n + c_2n^{1/2}$, we have
> $$
> \frac{mp(m)}{e^{cm^{1/2}}} > \frac{D + d}{2}
> $$
> Now we claim that for every $r_1$ there exists a $\delta_{r_1} = \delta(r_1)$ such that for $n \le m \le n + c_2n^{1/2}$,
> $$
> \frac{mp(m)}{e^{cm^{1/2}}} > d + \delta_{r_1}
> $$

Then he goes on to prove the lemma.

When I see statements such as "for every $r_1$ there exists a $\delta_{r_1}...$, or "there exist constants $c$ and $x_0$ such that some function $f(n) < cn^{1/2}$", I'm in complete awe. I can read, but can't easily understand such hard technical statements, though the prerequisites seem to be nothing  beyond a first course in real analysis, which I have met (I'm an undergrad student).

I want to learn how to create such technical arguments.Where does one go to get good at such things (None of my classes offer these sort of things)? What are some good resources for practicing?

Comment: Perhaps counterintuitively, I think the first step should be to gain a more intuitive (and less rigorous) understanding of what the _concepts_ in hard analysis are all about. For instance, can you figure what the lemma you cited is "really saying"? Once you gain some familiarity with the language, the techniques will start coming to you more and more quickly. But until you get to a point where you understand _intuitively_ what a theorem is, rather than purely formally, things will be pretty hard. At least, that was my experience.

Comment: If you can translate such statements into your natural language that would help a lot. Regarding the quantifiers like "for every" and "there exists" try to decode the statement "for every positive integer $n$ with $n>1$ there exists a prime number $p$ such that $n$ is divisible by $p$". The problem is not in decoding quantifiers in analysis but the statement after quantifiers. You need to get used to the kind of statements used in analysis compared to those used in other branches like algebra.

Comment: As for books, properly reading baby rudin is invaluable. There's also "Asymptopia" by Spencer and Florescu, which I can't recommend highly enough. I found my intuitive grasp of analysis got better after reading Goldblatt's "Lectures on the Hyperreals", which does nonstandard analysis (i.e. it freely uses infinitesimals). Statements with infinitesimals tend to have fewer quantifiers, which makes them easier to understand intuitively. You might also read everything on Terry Tao's blog. He has some posts with very intricate analysis where he explains the ideas behind the analysis very well.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks for your comment, I find it valuable. To gain intuition, I think that a systematic treatment of such concepts and a large number of exercises will help me.